# Rewind/Forward SWF with background audio

Tags: flash, reverse, timeline, audio

I have a Flash animation (AS2) that contains a background audio file. I've been asked to add controls to it. So far, I have added buttons to pause/play the animation and stop and start both the root timeline and the attached mp3 audio. I also need to add a reverse button. I've seen tutorials that are enable reversing of the timeline's playhead. Is there a way to have the audio file reverse as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to play the sound in reverse? Unfortunately, I am rather sure there is not an answer for this. AS2 doesn't allow you to manipulate frame sound objects like this (even with the sync type of steam). Even programmatically, I don't remember AS2 having the sound utilities to reverse the audio.

However, a clever hack might be to record the audio in reverse. When you do the rewind, you can plan the reversed sound at the reversed point in the playhead that the regular sound from playing. I can't see how this can be too practical though unless you have a specific use-case for it.

Comment: The sound doesn't need to play in reverse, but the sound would need to restart at the correctly synch'd point that play resumes.